# Is it possible to win Castle of the Winds without the teleport spell?

Tags: castle-of-the-winds

I'm blocked in Castle of the Winds. I've gotten to a spot in the game that I can't find a way deeper into the dungeon. I know the dungeons are dynamically created so I figure it might have blocked me off.

Is Teleport required to make it the rest of the way?

Comment: Holy cow, I'm not the only one to remember this game!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Teleport is not required.

It's probable that there's a path hidden by a secret/hidden door though.  Try searching around the areas you've explored by pressing the 's' key. It greatly helps having the clairvoyance spell to find possible secret door spots, but is not required.

Comment: It was a hidden door.  I had completely forgot about those. Thanks.

Comment: I remember before I knew about 'search'ing, the first dungeon had me in a twist.  I thought that I had to keep using Phase Door (read Teleport Jr.) to get into the room with the Scrap Parchment.